# Option unicode=true with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, unicode, portability

Is there a drawback when using the option `unicode=true` with the package hyperref and the engines  PDFTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX?

In other words, can a portable document always have `\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}`?

Comment: Could you state what you mean exactly with "portable" here. Portable between different LaTeX compilers? Or different PDF viewers and/or OSs?

Comment: @MartinScharrer between different LaTeX compilers (the mentioned ones)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as my experience goes, all reasonably recent versions of Adobe's PDF Reader, Gnome's Evince, and Mac OSX's Preview support unicode bookmarks.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced issues with Adobe Acrobat Reader for Linux when the `unicode` option was enabled. The displayed page numbers only contained garbled unicode letters. Definitively not a way you want to pass important PDF around.
But this might be reader dependent. The Linux version has some other bugs and so it is likely it is only an issue with this version.

See my `comp.text.tex` post about it:
[[unicode]{hyperref} results in garbled page numbers in Acrobat Reader 9.4.2 02/11/2011 Linux](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/hyperref$20unicode/comp.text.tex/omYdivfRxRM/ZWILUF60BFsJ)

The error looks like:

[image]

Comment: But this is an issue of Acrobat Reader for Linux (which I could verify for version 9), not an issue of hyperref portability, no? Other Linux-based PDF readers I tried - some equally ancient as AcroRd 9 - do not exhibit this problem.

Comment: @DevSolar: Sure it is. That is what I wrote! :-) It is worse mentioning. A lot of LaTeX people also use Linux and some of them like to use Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

This `unicode=true` just worked fine for me in Greek, in a Miktex - lualatex installation. Adobe Reader, Foxit and Texstudio own, could display this perfectly in greek.